# React Native iOS - Hermes is enabled in Podfile, but isn't enabled in app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-hermes

I'm trying to enable Hermes in my React Native 0.65 app for iOS. I've followed the documentation to enable Hermes by making this change to my Podfile:

```
use_react_native!(
     :path => config[:reactNativePath],
     # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
-    :hermes_enabled => false
+    :hermes_enabled => true
   )
```

Then I cleaned the build folder, ran `pod install`, and rebuilt my app for a physical iOS device in debug mode. However, running the following code provided by React Native in my app shows that Hermes is actually disabled:

`const isHermes = () => !!global.HermesInternal; // <-- returns false`

How can I enable Hermes in my app? I'm running React Native 0.65.1 and recently upgraded from 0.64.2. Thank you.

Comment: Try use `npx react-native-clean-project` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. You must uninstall app on device/emulator, then rebuild from xcode.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check against the `undefined` value. putting `!!` will evaluate to boolean.